# Is there any flaw in a given proof of letter (a)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

The question and its answer is given below:

> [image]

I prefer the above proof than the below one:

> [image]
>   [image]

Is there any flaw in the first proof?

Comment: There is  nothing wrong with the first proof except that $N$ should be $n$.